# Filtering LINQ query

Tags: asp.net, linq, filtering

I have problem that is bothering me last couple of days.

I need to filter LINQ query using comboboxes and textboxes. The problem is I can't manage to get the result and I always get the empty gridview (used for showing filtered data).

Can anyone help me why am I getting no results at all? I've checked the debugger and the data sent to query is valid, although, I'm not sure about "string.Empty" value.

Here is the code:

```
string naziv, nazivEn, adresa, tel, fax, mob, email, web, oib, tip, mjesto;


        if (chkMjesto.Checked == true)
        {   
                    mjesto = cbMjesto.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
        else
            {
            mjesto = string.Empty;
            }

        if (chkTip.Checked == true)
        {
            tip = cbTip.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            tip = string.Empty;
        }

        string tema;

        if (chkTema.Checked == true)
        {
            tema = cbTema.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            tema = string.Empty;
        }

        if (chkAdresa.Checked == true)
        {
            adresa = txtAdresa.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            adresa = string.Empty;
        }

        if (chkTelefon.Checked == true)
        {
            tel = txtTelefon.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            tel = string.Empty;
        }

        if (chkMobitel.Checked == true)
        {
            mob = txtMobitel.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            mob = string.Empty;
        }

        if (chkEmail.Checked == true)
        {
            email = txtEmail.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            email = string.Empty;
        }

        if (chkWeb.Checked == true)
        {
            web = txtWeb.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            web = string.Empty;
        }

        if (chkOIB.Checked == true)
        {
            oib = txtOIB.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            oib = string.Empty;
        }

        if (chkNaziv.Checked == true)
        {
            naziv = txtNaziv.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            naziv = string.Empty;
        }

        if (chkNazivEn.Checked == true)
        {
            nazivEn = txtNazivEn.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            nazivEn = string.Empty;
        }

        if (chkFax.Checked == true)
        {
            fax = txtFax.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            fax = string.Empty;
        }          


        if (rblOrganizator.SelectedItem.Value == "Nije")
        {
            var pretraga = from t in db.tijeloes
                           where t.tijelo_naziv.Contains(naziv) && t.tijelo_adresa.Contains(adresa) && t.tip_tijela.tip_tijela_naziv.Contains(tip) && t.mjesto.mjesto_naziv.Contains(mjesto) 
                           where t.tijelo_telefon.Contains(tel) && t.tijelo_fax.Contains(fax) && t.tijelo_email.Contains(email) && t.tijelo_mob.Contains(mob) && t.tijelo_web.Contains(web) && t.tijelo_oib.Contains(oib) && t.tijelo_naziv_en.Contains(nazivEn)
                           select new { t.tijelo_naziv, t.tijelo_oib,t.tip_tijela.tip_tijela_naziv,t.tijelo_adresa,t.mjesto.mjesto_naziv, t.mjesto.zupanija_drzava.zupanija_naziv};

            gvTijelo.DataSource = pretraga;
            gvTijelo.DataBind();

            if (pretraga.Count() != 0)
            {
                gvTijelo.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "Naziv";
                gvTijelo.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = "OIB";
                gvTijelo.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Text = "Tip tijela";
                gvTijelo.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Text = "Adresa";
                gvTijelo.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Text = "Mjesto";
                gvTijelo.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Text = "Regionalni centar";
            }

        }
```

Comment: `string.Empty` is a constant equal to `""`, i.e., a string of length 0.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, but why do I get empty gridview is still unknown...

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005920/is-there-a-better-way-of-writing-this-linq-query/5006024#5006024. Can you see the SQL generated for that query? That would help.

Comment: It would be helpful if you pared down your question & code to a specific case (selected values) that you *know* should return results.

Comment: Well, if it is of any help when I was filtering the query I was using the values that I know that should return the result. Actually, if I leave everything unchecked isn't it that it should display all the results from the database?

Comment: Is any of those database fields nullable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string.Empty seems to the culprit. I would bet the SQL being generated is checking if a field contains '', which just won't likely work with data in that field.

Your best bet is to start the query before your conditionals, then append a where to it if the corresponding check box is checked.

```
var pretraga = db.tijeloes;
if (chkMjesto.Checked == true)
{   
    pretraga = pretraga.Where(t => t.tijelo_naziv.Contains(cbMjesto.SelectedItem.Text));
}
if (chkTip.Checked == true)
{
    pretraga = pretraga.Where(t => t.tip_tijela.tip_tijela_naziv.Contains(cbTip.SelectedItem.Text));
}
...

pretraga = pretraga.Select(t => new { t.tijelo_naziv, t.tijelo_oib,t.tip_tijela.tip_tijela_naziv,t.tijelo_adresa,t.mjesto.mjesto_naziv, t.mjesto.zupanija_drzava.zupanija_naziv });
// Bind to pretraga.
...
```

Comment: Remember, LINQ will not execute the query until it needs to. You are just building a tree with each Where for it to execute later. Upon binding the query to your Grid, the query will finally execute with only the appropriate Where conditions in place.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! I'll give it a try immediately. The problem is I have similar problems with LINQ queries that have joins inside them and I'm not sure how will I be able to recreate queries like that. Thank you once again.

Comment: When you have to conditionally join other data, you can do something similar with the Join/GroupJoin extension methods. All of the C# "syntactic sugar" (the "from t in something", "where t.Something == myVar", etc.) gets translated into corresponding extension methods. It's these methods that are ideal for chaining together a truly dynamic query with complex conditions. Good luck!

Comment: Amazing, if you ever come to Croatia, let me know, I want to buy you a beer! Works like a charm. String.Empty was the problem.

Comment: Perhaps on my next trip to Italy! Although, I'd still be a couple hundred kilometers away. I'm glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would declare all the variables at the top seperately like

```
string naziv = string.empty;
string whatever = string.empty;  etc
```

Doing this will make your code smaller because you can get rid of the else statements as the variables are already set.

Sorry not a solution but might thin down the code for you a little :)

Comment: Yeah, definitely not the solution, but it is helpful! ;) Thank you!